# System of non-linear ODE's: How to express using transition matrices using Euler's forumla

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of differential equations:

$dy_i / dx = c_i(y_{i-1}^4 - y_{i}^4) +f_i$    (for i=1,...,n)

that I am desperately trying to express as follows (using Euler's method):

$\textbf{y}(t_{k+1})=\boldsymbol{C_1}\boldsymbol{y}(t_{k})+\boldsymbol{C_2}\boldsymbol{y^4}(t_{k}) + \boldsymbol{f}$

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are transition matrices (i.e. stochastic matrices) in the finite difference equations. I have tried expressing as (where **y** = (y1, y2)'):

$\frac{d\boldsymbol{y}}{dt} = \boldsymbol{F}(t,\boldsymbol{y})=\begin{pmatrix}
-c_1y_1^4\\ c_2(x^4-y^4)\end{pmatrix}$

However this does not produce the equation in the desired form (which is necessary for a  simulation technique I will subsequently apply). Note $f_i = 0$ for all i except $i=1$, where it's equal to 1. We may assume $y_1(0)=1$ and $y_2(0)=0$. The idea is taken from: https://www.witpress.com/Secure/elibrary/papers/CE99/CE99014FU.pdf (see the two equations at the bottom of page 6).

I am really stuck with this one, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Skip this problem for a moment and have a look at Euler's method for $y'(t) =g(y(t))$. Write the iteration as $v_{k+1} = v_k + h g(v_k)$, where $h$ is your timestep. You just have a to figure out what $g$ looks like in your case. To that end, have a look a matrix which has minus ones on the main diagonal and ones on the first subdiagonal. What is the effect of multiplying this matrix from the left on a vector $x = (x_1^4,x_2^4,\dotsc,x_n^2)$?

Comment: I see that this is an updated version of your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297621/eulers-method-for-system-of-non-linear-odes 
It is best to avoid duplication of questions. Since you have received answers elsewhere, I recommend that you update your other question with the .pdf reference and delete this question. Then we keep all information in one place for the benefit of all.